# Coredata Fetchrequest Foreach loop with subsections of data and sort methods

Tags: core-data, swiftui, foreach

I have a data model entity called `Object` laid out like so:

```
name: String
createdDate: Date()
updatedDate: Date()
```

My fetch request:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.updatedDate, order: .reverse)]) var objects: FetchedResults<Object>
```

I want to have my list of objects sorted with the most recently updated (keyed off `updatedDate`) at the top. I chose this sort method, because when combined with `withAnimation` I get a real nice animation when items lower in the list are updated and move to the top.

When the user creates a new object however, it goes to the bottom of the list because this new object doesn't have a value for `updatedDate` (intentional because my users tell the app when an object is updated). This behaviour makes sense but is undesired.

My current `ObjectListView` looks like this (simplified to focus on my question):

```
struct intervalsExist: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.updatedDate, order: .reverse)]) var objects: FetchedResults<Object>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(objects) { object in
                NavigationLink {
                    ObjectDetailView(object: object)
                } label: {
                    Text(object.name ?? "Unknown name")
                }
                .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                    withAnimation {
                    // Update `updatedDate` with current Date()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like is for my list of objects to be presented as such:

```
---
Object with no updatedDate, most recent
Object with no updatedDate
Object with no updatedDate

Object with updatedDate, most recent
Object with updatedDate
Object with updatedDate
---
```

Where `objects with updatedDate` will reorder themselves to the the newest at the top when they are updated.

I tried using 2 sort methods in my fetch request, like so:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
    SortDescriptor(\.createdDate, order: .reverse),
    SortDescriptor(\.updateDate, order: .reverse),
]) var objects: FetchedResults<Object>
```

While this gets me the ordering I am looking for above, **items no longer re-order themselves within the list** which is a key part of what I'm trying to build.

Comment: You could create a computed property in an extension to your entity that returns the update or create date depending on if the update date is nil and sort on this property. If I remember correctly you need to mark this property with `@objc` to work with the sort descriptor.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Would you mind helping me understand how to do that? I'm still very new to SwiftUI.